# Remove security message using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While running Selenium automated tests on Chrome, I get following type of error message:

`You're using an unsupported command line flag: ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer`

[image]

Can someone please suggest how can I remove it using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set mode "test-type" to ChromeDriver capabilities

Here's my sample code in Java

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type", "start-maximized",
     "no-default-browser-check");    
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Comment: Thanks, Nguyen Vu Hoang!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome version 35.x, this kind of pop-up will come. Try using chrome version 34.x and then see.

Actually its the problem with chrome builds. Just give it a try.

Thank you,
Shravan Kumar.T